# Build a dynamic nav bar that reads from array using Angular2+?

Tags: angular, navigation, uinavigationbar

I have a top nav and a side nav. Every side nav tab has a different set of top navs that all follow the same format. Instead of making a new top nav component page for each side nav tab, how do I populate the top nav based off an id or something that is respective to an array of values?

I know how to manually make a top nav, but I want the template to be the same, looping through the array creating a top nav element for each element in the array.

I am using angular5, so no jquery please :) Typescript would be great!
Thanks!

Comment: So what have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: I havent tried anything! I have it manually hand coded what values are listed for the top nav bar. I don't really know how to go about making it dynamic since I am new to typescript and angular

Comment: Then I'd recommend some research and a few attempts before asking. SO isn't here to write code for you.

Answer (score 0):

What you should to do is passing the right data on every click of the side nav, so the top nav will be updated with the correct data.
Your parent component  should contain all arrays and you should pass these arrays to the top nav on every click of the side nav.
you can intercept the click of the side nav by using event emitter and `@Output` annotation

**home-page.component.ts**

```
     export class HomePageComponent implements OnInit {

                  private navbartitles :string[];
                  private navbarlinks :string[];

                  sideNavClicked(sideNavId) {
                    // You should make a list of data for every side nav 
                    // You have also to make a condition using the sideNavId and pass the correct 
                    // data on every side nav click
                    // the data below will be passed to the top nav bar component
                  if(sideNavId === 'firstSideNav') { 
                  this.navbartitles= ['title1','title2','title3'] ;
                  this.navbarlinks= ['link1','link2','link3'] ;}
                    }
                }
```

the home page html should contain both top nav and side nav components and side nav should emit click events.

**home-page.component.html**

```
<app-my-side-bar (sideNavBarClicked)='sideNavClicked($event)'></app-my-side-bar>
<app-my-top-bar [navbartitles]="navbartitles" [navbarlinks]="navbarlinks"></app-my-top-bar>
```

And finally your top nav bar should just display the data passed by **HomePageComponent**

**my-top-bar.component.ts**

```
export class MyTopBarComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() private navbartitles :string[];
  @Input() private navbarlinks :string[];
}
```

**my-top-bar.component.html**

```
nav class = "navbar navbar-default" role = "navigation">

  <div *ngFor="let title of navbartitles;let i= index"  class = "navbar-header">
     <a class = "navbar-brand" href = "{{navbarlinks[i]}}">{{title}}</a>
  </div>  
</nav>
```